# How to write huge rows of data using r tableGrob

Tags: r, gridextra

How to write more than 1000 rows of data into as table  in a grid view port using tableGrob in r .

Comment: Why would you want to paste 1000 rows into a grid viewport? Surely it would be impossible to read? Perhaps you could explain your question some more and post a sample of the data concerned. Your question is unanswerable as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works just fine if you have enough time

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)

pdf("y.pdf", height=22, width=0.05)
grid.table(sample(letters, size = 1001, TRUE), theme=ttheme_minimal(2, padding = unit(c(0,0),"mm")))
dev.off()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ9IW.png)

Comment: Thanks for reply actually I tried same grid.table(data), it is printing but table is overflowing and some of lines are coming in view port. How to split that table into multiple pages or side by side. My table consists more than 1000 rows and 3 columns